# ¿Como añadir un enlace con id en los botones de Woocommerce sin afectar el add-to-cart de los productos?

Tags: javascript, php, woocommerce, google-ads

Estoy tratando de configurar google ads en mi instalación de wordpress+woocommerce. La duda radica que en el paso a paso de medir los clicks a los botones google me pide agregar un onclick ejemplo:

```html
<button
  onclick="return gtag_report_conversion('http://example.org/your-link')"
>Enviar</button>
```

Entonces he hecho el siguiente JS agregando el onclick correspondiente a los botones de mis productos en woocommerce, el cual agrega el respectivo onclick que deseo en cada botón de mis productos

```javascript
var addOnClickButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.add_to_cart_button');

addOnClickButtons.forEach(function(link) {
  link.setAttribute(
    'onclick', 
    "return gtag_report_conversion('https://example.org/');"
  );
});
```

El problema está ahora, que todos los botones de woocommerce tiene un **add-to-cart=id-del-producto** *(Ejemplo: https://midominio.org/tienda/?add-to-cart=4315)* y en el fragmento de JS anterior al dar click me añade el producto al carrito, pero me redirige al home del sitio ya que esta agregado el dominio raíz únicamente.

A lo que pregunto, ¿Es posible añadir el enlace "dinámico" de los productos al fragmento de JS anterior en la url, y con ello se pueda medir cada boton con su id correspondiente y no estatico como lo tengo actualmente?